# asp text commands to modify text on buttons, labels, or textboxes

Tags: text, asp-classic, tags, symbols

I have no idea what this is called, but when you have `Text = "TEXT TEXT <br /> TEXT TEXT"`
where can I find a list of the `"<br />"` type of modification symbols?

Sorry for the dumb question, just don't know what this is called.

Comment: It's called HTML. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Html)

Comment: no no it edited my comment..translating what i put in into the actual TAGS. I mean this:  & l t ; b r  /  & g t ;   equaling a  <br />.. I need to just be able to use those to edit text in text boxes dynamically from server side.... which is why i'm asking =\   specifically for right now bold and underlines, but a list would be great.

Comment: Ah....you need to convert "<br />" to chr(10).

Comment: that's it. Thanks! I guess this is called decoding the <br /> ? Appreciate your help!

Comment: chr(10) it's a control character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you are after is HTML *encoding* which will convert such string:

`TEXT TEXT <br /> TEXT TEXT`

To this:

`TEXT TEXT &lt;br /&gt; TEXT TEXT`

To achieve this, classic ASP has built in method called `Server.HTMLEncode` which is explained in detail [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Real use example:

```
<%
strRawData = "TEXT TEXT <br /> TEXT TEXT"
strEncoded = Server.HTMLEncode(strRawData)
%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using break command.Instead br/ you can use only br (inside <> as a tag) for line break. There are more commands in vbscript which can be used in classic asp. Go [To this link](http://powerasp.net/content/new/vbscript-constants.asp)